# ¿Como puedo crear un json en visual basic?

Tags: json, visual-basic

Tengo este archivo JSON y necesito pasar su formato en visual studio como código de visual basic para poder enviarlo y consumir una api que necesito para crear los perfiles necesarios del sistema que estoy desarrollando

```
{
 "name": "TC Tienda01",
 "business_hours": {
 "monday": [
  {
    "open": "08:00",
    "close": "13:00"
  },
  {
    "open": "15:00",
    "close": "18:00"
  }
],
"tuesday": [
  {
    "open": "08:00",
    "close": "18:00"
  }
],
"wednesday": [
  {
    "open": "07:00",
    "close": "10:00"
  }
]
},
"location": {
"street_number": "#1010",
"street_name": "Calle 2",
"city_name": "Santiago",
"state_name": "RM",
"latitude": 4.667034,
"longitude": -74.05306,
"reference": "Local 2"
},
"external_id": "Tienda01"
}
```

Las clases las genere por la herramientas de visual studio y me las dio pero lo que no se es como asignarle a los valores anidados en business_hours y location ya que me da error de referencia de objeto.
Cabe aclarar que estoy aprendiendo a como usar este lenguaje de programación

Las clases del archivo JSON

```
Public Class Rootobject
 Public Property name As String
 Public Property business_hours As Business_Hours
 Public Property location As Location
 Public Property external_id As String
End Class

Public Class Business_Hours
 Public Property monday() As Monday
 Public Property tuesday() As Tuesday
 Public Property wednesday() As Wednesday
End Class

Public Class Monday
 Public Property open As String
 Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Tuesday
 Public Property open As String
 Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Wednesday
 Public Property open As String
 Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Location
 Public Property street_number As String
 Public Property street_name As String
 Public Property city_name As String
 Public Property state_name As String
 Public Property latitude As Single
 Public Property longitude As Single
 Public Property reference As String
End Class
```